# Facebook apps will be still be login while you are logged out from facebook, How?

Tags: facebook, api, codeigniter

I am working on the facebook apps, I got problem like when I logged out from facebook, my facebook apps will still be logged in. Can please any body help me on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be because your Facebook session for your app is not destroyed. The session for your application is maintained separate from the Facebook's session. You might also add the logout button on your app so you could explicitly logout.

Comment: Appreciated, But I have done the logout of the facebook.

Comment: what if i have logged out of facebook app and then installed my app which uses facebook login, what happens then as per SOP? Mine behaves unusually